# How to set a custom folder with `UIFileSharingEnabled=YES`?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, itunes

I have added `UIFileSharingEnabled = YES` into application's .plist-file. And now I may see a folder on iTunes on device settings (tab "Applications"):

```
My Folder
```

But I need to get access to files inside this folder.

```
File1.txt
File2.txt
```

How to change a folder from the root to my folder on iTunes?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. The folder which you see in iTunes is the Documents directory of your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. iTunes only shows the contents of the app's `Documents` directory. iTunes doesn't let a user view the contents of folders inside `Documents`.